# Ranking boxers in order of their strength in minimum number of days

Tags: mathematics

**1024 boxers are to be ranked in order of strength:**
The following are given:

- No two boxers have the same strength
- In any match, the stronger boxer always wins
- A boxer may fight in only 1 match per day

How many days will it take to rank all the boxers by strength?

My approach till now: 
Find total number of matches - 1024C2 
 Then divide them with number of matches that can be held in single day - 512. 
This will include repitition as well i.e if AB played and then BC played A won the against B and B won the match against C, then AC do not need to play because we know A would rank above C.

Not able to find an approach that I can apply to 1024 players.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! All questions here *must* include a proper source. (In addition, even if you edit in a source, this question is likely to be closed as off-topic because it is a math problem rather than a puzzle.)

Comment: This puzzle has been asked by one of my colleague. 
Does mentioning his name counts as proper attribution?

Could not figure that out from this link:https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Since the question is closed and @UtsavPatel might still want an answer, here it is: https://pastebin.com/PPtvdGPV

Comment: @classicalMpk Thanks, I added comments in the pastebin you posted. Can you have a look at it?

Comment: @classicalMpk I appreciate that you're trying to help, but please don't answer closed questions in the comments, otherwise there's no point in us closing questions at all.

Comment: How can I start the chat with @classicalMpk

Comment: It is an interesting problem.  Too bad you guys closed it.  What if Utsav's colleague came up with it?